# Mount point for data partition during installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I have created a `/home` home partition for files that change frequently (programming files, built libraries, etc.). And I would like to create another `data` partition to store files that rarely change or move (such as a very large dataset), so that these files won't scatter around or cause fragmentation in a `/home` partition.

How do I choose the mount point properly for the `data` partition during Ubuntu 16.04 installation? And after I coose the mount point, how do I access it from the Ubuntu terminal.

**Note**

In the figure below

- `/dev/sda5` is mounted at `/home` with `ext4` file type
- The drop list *currently showing* is for `/dev/sda6`

[image]

Comment: You don't need to create a separate partition for this purpose. But you can enter e.g. `/home/data`.

Comment: I don't think /home is required: You can't have 2 /home.

Comment: @Pilot6, Oh, I just realize that I can enter the mount point manually as well, not only selecting from the drop list. So to clarify, by entering `/home/data` on `sda6`, the effect would be different from mounting both drive at `/home` (I mean extending `sda5` all the way to the end `sda6`) and then creating a folder `data` inside `/home`?

Comment: You can have `/home/data` folder as a simple folder in `/home/data`, or you can have a separate partition for that mounted to this point. It will look the same way from inside the system. But you can format your data partition to a different file system. That's the only reason I can imagine of having a separate partition.

Comment: @JerareYoshi, Thanks for pointing that out that I can't have 2 `/home`. I just realized that I can enter the mount point manually as well, as suggested in Pilot6's first comment.

Comment: @Pilot6, Thanks. I guess your suggestion is the answer. By mounting `sda6` at `/home/data`, it looks the same from inside, but the partition is separate.

Comment: I was just hoping that the system doesnt have to jump around over my big data files (~100 GB) when accessing files in `/home`, which would happen if I had put these big files with small files in the same partition.

Comment: System doesn't "jump" over files anyway. It works a different way.

Comment: @Pilot6, Maybe I use the wrong word, but please correct me if I am still wrong about the following: My general understanding is that if the file is badly fragmented (stored over different parts of the disk drive), then the moving head of the disk needs to jump to each fragment when retrieving the file; so the access maybe slow.  And I thought that this might happen if I put small files (which frequently change and move) in the same partition with large data files (to be specific, dataset file for programming stuff).

Comment: This a long story. But generally `ext4` is not much affected by fragmentation. This is NTFS practice. But you can use XFS, etc too. It is to complex to be discussed in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101446/discussion-between-ignite-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

It appears not to be possible to define a custom mount point within the installer. It is designed only to assign system partitions. Thus, just create the partition that you will use for Data, but do not specify a mount point.

Once the system is installed, you can use the utility "Disks" to have your data partition formatted and mounted automatically to a folder of your choice.